# Why does fit give an error when using tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels

When a try to generate a fit, an error message appears:

> Error in apply(x$counts, 1, min) :must have a positive greeting

Why am I getting this error?

---

Code to reproduce

```
model <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm")

base_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model)

formula_wf <- base_wf %>%
  add_formula(mpg ~ cyl + log(disp))

fit(formula_wf, mtcars)
```

Comment: With the library calls , `library(parsnip) ; library(workflows)` your code runs without error. So seems like a local issue. To help debug can you edit your question with the results of `sessionInfo()` please. Also does this error persist in a fresh R session without loading any previous workspace?

Comment: it worked after start a new session!!! thanks!!